# Swift: 'NSArray?' is not convertible to 'NSArray?'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently developing my first iOS app with Swift 2.0. I'm getting the following error:

```
'NSArray?' is not convertible to 'NSArray?'
```

At this line:

```
if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray{
```

Full code snippet:

```
do{
   let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

   if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray{
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         self.tableData = results
         self.appsTableView!.reloadData()
      })
   }
}catch let error as NSError{
   print(error)
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

My complete function: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqZJn.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the compiler with too many (superfluous) type annotations.

```
// tested in Playground
if let results = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray {
  // do something with results
}
```

Make sure you keep the spacing intact as well.

For completeness, here is how I set up `jsonResult`. The question if jsonResult itself is an optional or not has nothing to do with your error message.

```
let jsonResult = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["results" : [1,2,3,4,5]])
```

EDIT: Swift 2 version with try catch syntax

```
var originalDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["results" : [1,2,3,4,5]])
do {
    let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(originalDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
    let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? NSDictionary
    if let results = jsonResult!["results"] as? NSArray {
        for x in (results as! [Int]) {
            print("\(x)")
        }
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.description)
}
catch {
    print("no clue what went wrong")
}
```

Comment: If I make it like this: `if let results = jsonResult["results"]as? NSArray{` it says: 'NSArray?' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do have a problem with spacing, right? You need to show how you construct your jsonResult variable. Please post this by editing your original question. Apparently, it is an optional NSDictionary (`NSDictionary?`), so you need to first unwrap it. (Force unwrap with `!` as suggested by Leo might be risky.)

Comment: It also depends on how you define your `tableData` array.

Comment: I have edited my question. Here is a screenshot of my complete function: http://i.imgur.com/fCS73LF.png

Comment: Here you have a complete working example without the error: http://pastebin.com/vcSECgeF

Comment: Nope, since I'm using Swift 2.0 I have to use the do catch method instead of the final 'let'. Otherwise it generates the error: "Extra argument 'error' in call".

Comment: OK find the complete, error-free, Swift 2 compatible version in my edited answer.

Comment: You shouldn't force unwrap `jsonResult`, that will crash if it isn't a dictionary.

Comment: Spaces around Swift operators like as? or NOT OPTIONAL. Swift should get you into nice typing habits.

Comment: @gnasher729 I like the spaces as well. That was my very first comment. Sloppy typing, sloppy thinking.